# How can my RedApp retrieve current PNR open in sabre red workspace

Tags: sabre

I am new to Sabre redapp development. My redapp use case is to get an event notification when a new booking is made and to get the currently opened PNR in the agent workspace.

1. I see that I can subscribe to events based on action code, but I
   do not know what the action code is for a new booking command. Also
   if I have to filter through all commands, what should I filter on?
2. Secondly I want to get the PNR opened in the workspace. The
   IWorkBenchService gives the WorkAreaData object, but it only has an
   API `isPNRPresent()`. How can I read the current PNR data into my
   Redapp?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is listen to the command that is used to close/save a reservation (aka PNR). After that, you can call the TravelItineraryRead webservice to get the PNR information.

In the SDK folder you will find a sample folder, and in that folder an plugin example called com.sabre.redapp.example.cf.sws-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-v20140313-1205 that implement a webservice call.

Also you can check the section: **Red App Help - Release 2.13.2 > Red App Dev Help 2.13.2 > Communications in Red Apps > Sabre Web Services Communications> Accessing Sabre Web Services** in the Sabre Red Apps Eclipse help.